# JavaFX Collections and JavaFX properties - XStream serialization problems

Tags: serialization, javafx, xstream

I am writing app in Java FX and I used Java FX Properties and Java FX Collections in my classes. I read that I can't serialize Java FX Collections, so i made it in this way:

```
public class PurchaseContainer implements Serializable{

 List<Purchase> listOfPurchases;
  @XStreamOmitField
  ObservableList<Purchase> observableListOfPurchases =  FXCollections.observableArrayList(); 
  private Date actualDate;
  int PurchaseID;
```

and I have here the method

```
  public void copyListForSerialization()
{
listOfPurchases = new ArrayList<Purchase>(observableListOfPurchases);

}
```

But it doesn't work. I suppose that problem can be Purchase class when I have properties like this:

```
public class Purchase implements Serializable{
  private IntegerProperty purchaseID;
  private IntegerProperty productID;
  private StringProperty specificProductName;
  private DoubleProperty cost; 
  private DoubleProperty discount;
  private StringProperty descriptionOfPurchase;
  private Date purchaseDate;
```

I read lots of tutorial but I haven't any idea to solve my problem. I've "Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space". But this is very short list, only 4 records. So, I don't think it's caused by memory. Have you any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XStream does not provide any converters for the JavaFX collections and properties. See the [discussion](https://github.com/x-stream/xstream/issues/14) on the XSteam github issue tracker. There is however the [XStreamFX](https://github.com/dooApp/XStreamFX) project that tries to fill that gap. However I found that especially the collection implementation for XStreamFX does not work, so I had to implement my own converter:

```
public class ObservableListConverter extends CollectionConverter implements Converter {

    public ObservableListConverter(Mapper mapper) {
        super(mapper);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
        return ObservableList.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object createCollection(Class type) {
        if (type == ObservableListWrapper.class) {
            return FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        }
        if (type.getName().indexOf("$") > 0) {
            if (type.getName().equals("javafx.collections.FXCollections$SynchronizedObservableList")) {
                return FXCollections.synchronizedObservableList(FXCollections.observableArrayList());
            }
        }
        return new SimpleListProperty<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList());
    }
}
```

The implementation of `createCollection` may vary depending on your needs. All you have to do then is to add this converter to your `XStream` instance:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.registerConverter(new ObservableListConverter(xstream.getMapper()));
```

I'm not sure if that resolves the issue with OutOfMemory, but this is the way to convert an ObservableList using XStream.